Next 14 Dynamic Canonical Url on the basis of locale
I am working on a Next.js 14 project and implementing dynamic metadata for SEO. The application supports two languages: English (en) and Arabic (ar). I have already implemented canonical tags, but I'm unsure how to handle the different language versions in my URLs. How should I manage canonical tags for both English and Arabic URLs?
import HomeSection from './_components/sections/home/HomeSection'
import { Metadata } from 'next';
export const metadata ={
  title: 'Home Page',
  description: 'Home description',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/en',
  alternates: {
    canonical: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  },
  openGraph: {
    siteName: 'test-ai',
    locale: 'en_US',
    type: 'website',
  },

}
export default function Home() {

  
  return (
    <>
   <HomeSection/>
    </>
  );
}

What I Tried:
I have attempted to generate dynamic metadata based on the URL in my Next.js 14 application. Specifically, I have set up canonical tags to handle SEO for bilingual content. However, I'm currently stuck with how to manage this between server-side and client-side rendering.
What I'm Expecting:
I expect the canonical tags to dynamically select and reflect the current URL for both English and Arabic versions of the site. This way, the canonical tags will be automatically adjusted based on the current language and URL, ensuring proper SEO for all pages.
